# How to pull signed docker images using dockerode NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a node js application that does basic docker operations like pull images, create, run, start and stop docker containers. I am using dockerode library. 
I want to enforce only trusted signed images are allowed to be pulled. 
According to docker documentation, setting env variable DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1. This is not feasible because I am invoking docker remotely.

Observation on command line: Without setting DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1, using flag --disable-content-trust=false will force only trusted images to be downloaded.

```
[root@vm ~]# echo $DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST

[root@vm ~]# docker pull --disable-content-trust=false docker/trusttest
Using default tag: latest
no trust data available
[root@vm ~]#
```

But, this is no effect when called from node js using dockerode api

Here is the node code:

```
function pullImage(imageId){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        docker.pull(imageId,{"disable-content-trust":"false"},(err,stream)=>{
            if(err){
                console.error("Docker pull failed for:" + imageId + "error:" + err);
                reject(err);
            }else 
                console.log("Docker image installed: " + imageId);
                resolve(true);
            }
        });
    });
}


pullImage('docker/trusttest',{}).then((v)=>{
    console.log("pull image successful", v);
}).catch((ex)=>{
    console.error("exception in pull image", ex);
});
```

This code downloads the image even though disable-content-trust=false. 
The question is am I passing the option parameters to docker.pull correctly ?
I can't find the documentation for option parameter values for dockerode. 
Any help is much appreciated.

Links:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/

https://github.com/apocas/dockerode

Comment: what tag of image? you should pull image with its tag, it's `latest` tag above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thanh Nguyen Van. Even with latest tag the issue is still the same.

Comment: @TakeItEasy
Did you find a solution to this? I recently landed into this problem and after lots of searching, I stumbled upon your question. Seems like dockerode still do not have any documentation on docker content trust.